# Background video in swiftui 2

Tags: ios, swift, background, swiftui, ios14

I'm trying to put a video in the background with swifui 2 and IOS 14

My goal is for the bar with the play button to disappear completely.

Normally with .disabled (true) the bar should disappear but this is not the case it is always present at the start of the video and disappears about 1 sec after the start of playback.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct TestBackground: View {
    private let player =  AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8")!)
    private let controler = AVPlayerViewController()
    init() {
        let control = AVPlayerViewController()
        control.showsPlaybackControls = true
    }
    var body: some View {
       
                    VideoPlayer(player: player)
                        
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        .disabled(true)

                        .onAppear() {
                            
                            player.isMuted = true
                            player.play()
                            
                        }
                        .onDisappear() {
                            // Stop the player when the view disappears
                            player.pause()
                        }
                .scaledToFill()
    }
}

struct TestBackground_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        TestBackground()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/12672179)

Comment: @TheGrandJ And now if not can you delete it please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VideoPlayer` doesn't expose properties to hide the controls. However, `AVPlayerViewController` does. It needs to get wrapped in `UIViewControllerRepresented`, though:

```
struct AVPlayerControllerRepresented : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var player : AVPlayer
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}

struct TestBackground: View {
    private let player =  AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8")!)

    var body: some View {
        
        AVPlayerControllerRepresented(player: player)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .disabled(true)
            
            .onAppear() {
                
                player.isMuted = true
                player.play()
                
            }
            .onDisappear() {
                // Stop the player when the view disappears
                player.pause()
            }
            .scaledToFill()
    }
}
```

In your original code, you were creating a `AVPlayerViewController` in `init`, but never actually using it.